# Project host for a small group developing a Facebook application

Tags: version-control, collaboration

I am starting a Facebook application with a couple of friends.  What good, free, online, collaborative project hosts can we use from home?

So far I am thinking about something similar to git, but with a graphical interface maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest [Github](http://github.com)

If you need a graphical interface to git, [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) might work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a combination of [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/) for source control and Google Docs for collaborative documents.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [bitbucket.org](http://bitbucket.org/) with [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) (on top of [hg](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/)).  TortoiseHg has better Windows support than git currently and sounds like it would fit your group better in general.  (Guessing on Windows, since you said nothing about that.)

Answer (score 0):

I would use [google code](http://code.google.com/) and use [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) as the graphical interface. Google code has wiki as well.